# Capistrano 3.1 deploy failed - bitbucket on windows 10 - "Error reading response length from authentication socket."

Tags: git, ssh, deployment, bitbucket, capistrano

I am actually getting a project back from another developer. I have a windows 10 machine, the repo is on bitbucket.
I have my ssh agent started and my ssh key added each time I launch my command line client (cmder).
I can connect to `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`, to my server so the ssh key seems to work.
I can also run `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` from my server and it is fine too.
My ruby version is 2.3.* and it doesn't seem to be a net-ssh problem.
On my ssh config file I have added the

```
Host mydomain.com
ForwardAgent yes
```

But each time I tried the `cap staging deploy` I got this error

```
DEBUG [1a76116b] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/home/domain/tmp/git-ssh-app-staging-user.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:user/domain-b2c.git HEAD )
DEBUG [1a76116b]       Error reading response length from authentication socket.
DEBUG [1a76116b]       Permission denied (publickey).  
DEBUG [1a76116b]       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I really don't know what to do right now. I have trying many solutions I saw for people with similar problems but nothing seems to work.
It is working fine for the other developer.
My ssh key was generated with git and it is on my local .ssh folder, on my server ssh_authorized keys and on my bitbucket profil settings. (Could it be needed to add it to the repository ssh key?)

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found so I will post the solution here:
On PC, you need to install Putty and launch Pageant with your id_rsa key inside.

And that's it!